# Trouble displaying user data from ASP.net Core 2.0 Model in javascript chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm a very novice programmer and I've been trying to display user data in a javascript chart (chartist.js to be exact).  Right now, I seem to be struggling getting the data from my model to the javascript.  The KitchenSavings model is various decimal values which I'm trying to display in the chart.  I have the alert line in to test to see what the values are.  The alert currently doesn't seem to trigger as there is no popup generated when running the program.  After reading a variety of entries and tutorials, I've put together the following code:

My controller looks like this:

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        private readonly HomeProfileContext _context;
        private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public DashboardController(HomeProfileContext context, IAuthorizationService authorizationService, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _authorizationService = authorizationService;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> DashboardData()
        {
            // this gets the users data from the database.
            var kitchensavings = await _context.KitchenSavings.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.OwnerID == _userManager.GetUserId(User));

           return Json(kitchensavings);
        }
    }
```

My script section looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {


            $(function () {
                $.getJSON("Dashboard/DashboardData", function (userkitchendata) {
                    var kitchen = JSON.parse(userkitchendata);
                    alert(kitchen);
                });
            });


            new Chartist.Bar('#ct-chart3',
                {
                labels: [//this will be months],
                series: [//this will be the data by month]
                },
                {
                    stackBars: true,
                    axisY:
                    {
                        labelInterpolationFnc: function (value)
                        {
                            return (value) + 'kWh';
                        }
                    }
                }).on('draw', function (data)
                {
                    if (data.type === 'bar')
                    {
                        data.element.attr(
                            {
                                style: 'stroke-width: 30px'
                            });
                    }
                });
    });

</script>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What is the JSON response your `DashboardData` action method returns ? can you post the sample response to the question ?

Comment: Let me give you a few answers as I'm not sure which you're looking for.  1.  When I set the alert to userkitchendata and remove the JSON.parse line, the alert says object Object.  2. When I run debug and look at the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.Json returned it breaks into 4 things.  Content Type: null, SerializerSettings: null, StatusCode: null, Value: the correct data I'm trying to bring over to my javascript chart.  3.  I'm not sure how to see what the userkitchendata looks like from the getJSON function.

Comment: just another comment - it appears that when I change it to JSON.stringify, it will display the data i'm trying to retrieve in my alert.  I'm looking to see how to work with that data on here now.